# Get just Inserted/Modified record based on updated_timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

I want to get just Inserted/Modified record based on updated_timestamp.

I have following scenario for `DB2` database:

1. Triggering `insert` or `update` query to DB. The table contains updated_timestamp field which capture the insert or updated time.
2. Want to get my previous inserted/ updated record only using `select` query.

**Example**

```
insert into table_name(x,y,CURRENT TIMESTAMP);
```

want to get the above inserted record using `select` as

```
select * from table_name where updated_timestamp > ?
```

with what value should I replace the `?`, above query should return me latest inserted record as `x,y,<time_stamp>`

Comment: trying to get the most recently inserted record for x,y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what your asking, couldn't you use a subquery pulling the max(updated_timestamp) and other values from the table and use that to filter to only the most recently updated records for each one?

Something like this:

```
insert into table_name (x, y, timestamp)
Select table_name.x, table_name.y, DateTime()
from table_name join (select x, y, Max(updated_timestamp) 
updated_timestamp from table_name) table_name2
on table_name.x = table_name2.x and table_name.y = tablename2.y
and table_name.updated_timestamp = table_name2.updated_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

if your db2 version as this option you can use final table like this

```
 SELECT updated_timestamp 
 FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO table_name  (X, X, updated_timestamp )
                VALUES(valueforX, valueforY, CURRENT TIMESTAMP));
```

look [IBM Doc](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_selectvalueinsert.html)

you can use a variable too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE YOURLIB.MYTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
INSERT INTO table_name  (X, X, updated_timestamp )
VALUES(valueforX, valueforY, YOURLIB.MYTIMESTAMP));
```

but the best solution is update your table with you primary key and get your timestamp with your primary key after.

A suggestion, you use trigger for update last timestamp. May be can you use autotimestamp like this :

```
CREATE TABLE table_name  
(
X VARCHAR(36),
Y VARCHAR(36),
CHANGE_TS TIMESTAMP FOR EACH ROW ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```